# How to enable logging in XStream?

Tags: logging, xstream, jvm-arguments

I am struggling to load a manually converted XML file with XStream. I do no longer receive an exception on unmarshalling it, but in the resulting objects, paths are null that I do not expect to be null.

Is there a way to enable debug logging in XStream to help me identify the problem (JVM arguments or via my logger config)? If not, suggestions on where to set breakpoints would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: Nope, I was able to solve my problem somehow, but not by enabling logging.